# Embed Instagram recent photos from my profile in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, instagram, instagram-api

I am trying to retrieve instagram feed (recent photos) from my profile (I want to embed those photos in my website). However I cannot achieve it with any library nor manual REST API call (both GET and POST):

https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/lazycangoo/media/recent/?access_token=ACCESS_TOKEN&count=9

Can you please support? It seems I do not know how to use the API..

Comment: post your code, please. Show us what you tried so we could help you

Comment: Actually I'm just trying to execute REST API call (desribed in the question) via Postman, so no code involved. I cannot force the API to work..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Documentation](https://www.instagram.com/developer/endpoints/users/#get_users_media_recent) says that to get a user's recent media, you should send a `GET` request to the following URL:

```
https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/{user-id}/media/recent/?access_token=ACCESS-TOKEN
```

What you are doing wrong is using `username` instead of `user_id`.

Try this:

```
https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/5136815/media/recent/?access_token=ACCESS-TOKEN
```

Comment: Thanks, documentation is a key!